# Query Active Directory under NT AUTHORITY/NETWORK SERVICE

Tags: .net, active-directory

I have a Windows Service running under the NETWORK SERVICE account and have a need to query Active Directory for extended information about users.

It looks like in this situation there are access restrictions that prevent the service from accessing Active Directory. And the service has to be run as NETWORK SERVICE, not domain user.

So far I'm passing credentials (login and password) of a domain user to DirectorySearcher. Credentials are retrieved from config file, which is, of course, not good.

Is there another more elegant way to query Active Directory from service running under the NETWORK SERVICE?

Comment: When you say "It looks like... there are access restrictions", do you mean you know there are or it's not working so you assume there are?  I ask because this should work.  Is there a firewall getting in the way?

Comment: It's not working for me, so my assumption is that there is something getting in the way.
I do not think it is firewall issue, because when I specify domain account to access AD it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless your domain administrator bans this deliberately, Active Directory by default allows any computer accounts to run LDAP query.

So, if your computer has joined to the domain, using NT AUTHORITY\Network Service account should just work.

Alternatively, you can set the domain user as the service account.  Then, you don't need to pass in any username or password into `DirectorySearcher`

Comment: For possible future users: I did the mistake of browsing from the server. I had logged on as theservername\adminuser and, of course, IE sent these credentials. The solution was to surf from a machine where I had logged on as thedomain\myuser. I wasted 30 minutes before I double palmed myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the computer account (COMPUTERNAME$) read permissions in Active Directory but as @Harvery Kwok said it should have this by default (if the computer is a domain member).